# Drupal $_SESSION write problems

Tags: php, session, drupal

I'm trying to use an external file to write a session variable that is accessible by a Drupal module.

The external script looks like:

```
define(DRUPAL_ROOT, getcwd());
include_once './includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);

session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['login']))
    $_SESSION['login'] = 'admin';
```

I also had this script check and see what Drupal variables it is able to see, and it can see $_SESSION['messages']. Drupal, however, ONLY sees $_SESSION['messages'] and not $_SESSION['login']. I have also tried this where:

```
$_SESSION['login'] = array('username' => 'admin');
```

My module tries to access this variable like so:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION))
    session_start();
if($username = trim($_SESSION['login']))
    ...
```

The error I get is that index 'login' is undefined. Any suggestions?

Comment: How and where is the external script called, and from where is the module called?

Comment: The external script is just a php file in the drupal directory. The module is just a very basic page-type module that is called directly.

Comment: Okay, but how is the external script called and by who? Remember, sessions are individual to one client, and carried over using session cookies. If your external script isn't called by the exact same browser instance, the session won't get carried over.

Comment: Another thing, I notice that you are calling `session_start()` manually. Isn't that something that Drupal will be doing during its bootstrap process anyway? I don't know for sure but I would suspect it does...

Comment: I thought it would start the session manually, but I would get $_SESSION undefined. The script is being called by me on the same browser I am accessing the module.

Comment: Strange. Are you on the same domain in the same directory? (Session cookies can be directory sensitive) Remember, `domain.com` is not equal to `www.domain.com`

Comment: Alright this is weird. The session variable appears in the module if I do a fresh page load after running the script, but not if I have the module open, run the script, and F5 the module.

Comment: I can work around this problem easily enough, though :)